# How to get the currentPath in Ember-cli

Tags: ember-cli

I have a simple `sidebar menu` which has an `ul` and several `li`. I would like to be able to arrange these `li`'s based on the `currentPath` in an `Ember-cli` application. It means for instance if I am in `xyz.index` template one of these `li` should not be shown. Therefore, I need to know what is `currentPath` in application. The `currentPath` can be something like `currentpage` in `Ruby on Rails`. What would be the best way to have `currentPath` in an `Ember-cli` application? Using `Ember-cli` version 0.2.7.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured in out by changing my approach to the problem. I just created a new state for `sidebar menu`.